# How to avoid animations to delay sub-elements animations?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a navbar element with a caret. When I hover on the element I would like the caret to turn and the color of the whole element to change.

Only Firefox shows the exact result while Safari shows opposite colors, and Chrome show a delay for the caret color change.

NB: Using Bootstrap

[Here is my Codepen](http://codepen.io/kikar/pen/pJeryp)

My CSS and HTML as follows:

```css
#navigation a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: color .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .5s ease;
  -o-transition: color .5s ease;
  transition: color .5s ease;
}

#navigation a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

#trigger .caret {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#trigger:hover .caret {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(1px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(1px);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(1px);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(1px);
}

.triggered {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;

  transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
  transition: all .5s ease-out .5s;
}

#trigger:hover ~ .triggered {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.triggered:hover,
.triggered:hover ~ .triggered {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

      <div id="navigation" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li id="trigger">
            <a>TRIGGER<span class="caret"></span></a>
          </li>

          <li class="triggered">
            <a>TRIGGERED 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="triggered">
            <a>TRIGGERED 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="triggered">
            <a>TRIGGERED 3</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I see both the colour change and the caret turning at exactly the same time. Chrome 43.

Comment: @JamieDixon I see 3 different things of 4 different browsers:
 - Chrome & Opera: Delayed
 - Safari: Opposite color on hoverOn and hoverOff
 - Firefox: Perfect, exactly how intended
(Latest version for each browser)